# Web Deploy on Windows Server 2016 is not working

Tags: windows, deployment, server, webdeploy

I have Server 2012r2 with IIS and web deploy configured and working there, I recently started migrating to 2016 server and can't have web deploy to work. Spent hours trying to find what I've done wrong and did not find any difference in how it's configured. Web management service responds to 8172 port but when I try to publish web site from VS 2015 it says service did not respond (without any delay). Why? The web deploy is good tool but only when it works, and if it does not work it will never help to resolve problems :(

Comment: This is an old question, but the title says Windows Server 2016, and the question itself refers to Server 2012r2.

Comment: @JakeJ If you read full question you would notice that it was a migration to 2016 server  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that reinstalling might have solved it, not downgrading. The order in which components are installed is important. Therefore a reinstall could have been the solution

Comment: Reinstall worked for me. Note, repair didn't work. The reinstall re-registered the handlers with WMSVC.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: removed 3.6 webdeploy and installed 3.5 everything works!

Comment: I think that reinstalling might have solved it, not downgrading. The order in which components are installed  is important. Therefore a reinstall could have been the solution.

Comment: Yes, I also think so. Why the hell the web deploy can't ask to install other components needed.